# NoMethodError when trying to access a "nested method" (or def) in the same module

Tags: ruby

The piece of code below gives me a `NoMethodError`. I'm a little confused why it gives me an error, and why I can't find anything about nesting methods in modules. Could someone please explain why this isn't working? Can I nest "defs" in modules?

```
module HowToBasic
  module_function

  def say_id_and_say_name(id)

    # nested method
    def say_id(id)
      p id
    end

    # errors here with `say_id_and_say_name': 
    # undefined method `say_id' for HowToBasic:Module (NoMethodError)
    # from teststuff.rb:24:in `<main>'
    say_id(id)
  end

end

HowToBasic.say_id_and_say_name("99999")
```

Version:
ruby 2.3.1p112

I had a look and couldn't find anything about this:

- relates to includes [NoMethodError when trying to access method defined in included module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066822/nomethoderror-when-trying-to-access-method-defined-in-included-module)
- relates to classes https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11665
- seems weird [Access a Ruby module's method within same module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35746974/access-a-ruby-modules-method-within-same-module)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're missing `self` keyword in method definition - without it `say_id_and_say_name` is just an instance method, thus it can't be invoked on Module.

```
module HowToBasic
  module_function

  def self.say_id(id)
    p id
  end

  def self.say_id_and_say_name(id)    
    say_id(id)
  end    
end

HowToBasic.say_id_and_say_name("99999")
```

Comment: Thanks. So the piece of code works if I just change `say_id(id)` to `self.say_id(id)`. Is there a place where you can point to read about "instance methods"?

Comment: Sure, there are a planty of places, here for example: http://culttt.com/2015/06/10/understanding-class-methods-verses-instance-methods-in-ruby/

By the way - you should avoid declaring methods within another method (I'm referring to `say_id`). I'll edit my answer in a minute so that you can see the proper definition.

Comment: Jordon, when Ruby parses your module `self` equals `HowToBasic`. Therefore, `def self.say_id(id)` is the same as `def HowToBasic.say_id(id)`. `self` is normally used in class method definitions, rather that the actual name of the object (actually, the module object). One reason for using `self` is that if you change the name of the module you don't have to change the definitions of the module methods. (This applies to classes also, as classes are modules.)  You can also define module methods in the module's singleton class, but that's a lesson for another day.